# c double argument being passed as wrong value

Tags: c, type-conversion, header-files

I am having an issue with double arguments for a probability function in C.

I have a function that takes a double as an argument:

```
int binomrand(double p, int n)
{
    int i;
    int numevents = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        numevents += bernoullirand(p);
    }
    return numevents;
}
```

I pass .85:

```
 int numcoach = binomrand(.85,COACH_SEATS);
```

but the minute I step into this function, Xcode shows p as such:

```
p   double  5.2511106800094658E-315
```

Which is off by a factor of at least 10^314.  This occurs even before calling bernoullirand, so I haven't included that code here.

E:

Since it was relevant, here was the .h declaration of binomrand:

```
int binomrand(float p, int n);
```

This was clearly wrong, but I didn't think to look at it.  Note that's "float" and not "double".

When I updated the function from float to double in its .c file, I neglected to do so in its .h file.  Multiple answerers realized this quickly.

Comment: Can you post a short, complete program that demonstrates this? Including any necessary function prototypes.

Comment: Where you called the function, was that from another file?  You need to have a function prototype for `binomrand` before you call it, otherwise it will try to pass an int as your argument instead of a double.

Comment: Thank you, JS1!  I forgot to update the header file when I was switching from floats to doubles.

Comment: That's why when you write foo.c and foo.h, the first thing foo.c should do is `#include "foo.h"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if you have not declared the function `binomrand` before first use or declared it incorrectly. Declare the function on the top of file where you actually use it or use proper header files.

```
int binomrand(double p, int n);  /* Declaration */
```